# how do i make a sprite running/sprint animation in html 5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, animation, html5-canvas, runtime

I am creating a 2D platformer game in html5 canvas. I am trying to animate a sprite so that it switches to a running image and a stationery image, to create the illusion that the sprite is running. I have tried changing the sprite images based on the frame number but it only shows the sprite running for less than a second. This is not my full code. Just the parts that are relevant to the running animation.

index.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Game</title>
    <style media="screen">
      #canvas {
        background-color: #87cefa;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js">

  </script>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
var canvas, ctx, player, playerPng, key, frameNo;
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
player = {
   w: 100,
   h: 200,
   x: 40,
   y: canvas.height - 20
}
playerPng = new Image();
frameNo = 0;
key = false;
function loop() {
   frameNo += 1;
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
   ctx.drawImage(playerPng, player.x, player.y, player.w, player.h);
   if(key === 39) {
      if(frameNo % 100 === 0){
         playerPng.src = "Running.png";
      } else {
         playerPng.src = "normal.png";
      }
   }
   if(key === false){
      playerPng.src = "normal.png";
   }
   window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
   key = e.keyCode;
});
window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
   key = false;
});
loop();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Load images once

First don't load the image every time you render it. `image.src = "filenameORUrl"` loads the image.

Load the images once then select which one you want to render.

#### Example create an load images

```
const running = new Image;   // create
const normal = new Image;
running.src = "Running.png"; //load
normal.src = "normal.png";
```

### Animate

To animate the image add the animation images to an array. Set a variable that defines how many frames each image should appear and then divide the frameNum by this value and floor it to get the image index.

#### Example animating the image

**Note** that in `(frameNo / runAnimFrames | 0)` the `| 0` (bitwise OR 0) floors the result. Is the same as `Math.floor(frameNo / runAnimFrames)`. Should only use OR zero on positive numbers less than `31 ** 2 - 1`

Example adds the animation sequence to the array `runAnim` and inside the main render loop displays the animation with each animation frame display for 30 frames `runAnimFrames` (half a second). Reduce the number to speed up the animation, increase to slow down.

You can add as many frames as you need to the animation array

```
const runAnim = [running, normal]; // add animation sequence to arr
const runAnimFrames = 30;   // number of frames to display each image in animation

// Inside main render loop
   if(key === 39) {
      const plyImg = runAnim[(frameNo / runAnimFrames | 0) % runAnim.length];
      ctx.drawImage(plyImg, player.x, player.y, player.w, player.h);
   } else {
      ctx.drawImage(normal, player.x, player.y, player.w, player.h);
   }
```